# Cirrus CI - Can't connect to MySQL additional container

Tags: mysql, docker, continuous-integration, cirrus-ci

I'm running a container on Cirrus CI, and in my `.cirrus.yml`, I've defined an `additional_container` to run a MySQL instance to test against as per the [docs](https://cirrus-ci.org/guide/writing-tasks/#additional-containers):

**.cirrus.yml**

```
container:
  image: node:latest
  additional_containers:
    - name: mysql
      image: mysql:8
      port: 3306
      cpu: 1.0
      memory: 512Mi
      env:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "pa55w0rd"
```

I'm trying to run a `CREATE DATABASE` command against that instance in one of my setup tasks:

```
...

mysql_setup_script:
    - mysql -uroot -ppa55w0rd -P3306 -hlocalhost -e "CREATE DATABASE voluble_test;"
...
```

I've installed the MySQL client (but not the server, as this would defeat the object) on my testing container. However, MySQL acts as if it were connecting to a *true* localhost DB and looks for a locally-installed MySQL server, it appears - and fails with the following error:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2 "No such file or directory")
```

That said, the Cirrus CI [docs](https://cirrus-ci.org/guide/writing-tasks/#additional-containers) state that the MySQL instance should be available at localhost:

> Tests will be able to access MySQL instance via localhost:3306.

I can't see an obvious way around this - any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `localhost` will cause mysql not to use the network.

Use either `127.0.0.1` or your docker host IP, depending on network configs.

Notice that the error is not a network error:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'
```

"through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'", that file does not point to a mysql socket inside your docker container.

Grab your docker host IP with:

```
$ docker network inspect bridge --format='{{ (index .IPAM.Config 0).Gateway}}'
```

Comment: Great stuff, cheers! I didn't realize that this special case existed for hosts supplied as 'localhost' but not for '127.0.0.1'!